# Ionic 2 setInterval variable scope

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am writing an app with Ionic 2 and am making good progress, but I just got hung up on something that I think is probably a simple fix.

I have text on the screen, after 5 seconds I want to update the text on the screen. I seem to lose access to the variable within the setInterval function.

```
constructor(public nav: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private getserver: GetServerService, storage: Storage) {
    this.storage = storage;

    this.storage.get('userAuth').then((name) => {
      if(name.id === undefined) {
          this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);  //kick back to login if no userdata
      }else{

          let options = {timeout: 120000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

            this.driverStatus = 'hi';  

            setInterval(()=> {
                this.driverStatus = 'Updated Text';
            }, 2000);

          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          },
          options
        );  
      }
    }); 

  }

}
```

When I run the app, it shows the text "Hello" but never updates the text to "Updated Text". The console shows the output properly.

I have tried suggestions from [Ionic2 function setInterval can't get a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525781/ionic2-function-setinterval-cant-get-a-parameter) but those suggestions did not work either. My other failed attempts are below.

```
var that = this;
setInterval(function() {
   that.userText = 'Updated Text';
}, 2000);
```

and

```
setInterval(()=> {
    this.userText = 'Updated Text';
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something about the Zones from Angular 2.
This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2)
You can fix it by injecting an NgZone's object and calling its run() method

```
setInterval(()=> {
   this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.userText = 'Updated Text';
   });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I have to include another file in order for ngZone to work. It didn't run out of the box.

I realized that I already had the gps coordinates I needed available on the previous window (to generate a map), so I just stored those and carried them over to this page, which negated my problem. It sped the app up a little bit that way too.

Comment: You have to mport it in your component and then inject it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NgZone, you can simple *bind* **this** as follow:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        that.userText = 'Updated Text';
    }.bind(this), 1000);
```